# pagerAnchorBuilder - trying to add classes

Tags: jquery-cycle

I'm using Cycle2 to build a carousel gallery and I've run into a little problem regarding styling the pager buttons. What I've gathered is that Cycle2 creates its own pager span tags for each slide which is a bummer becaus I've already styled my the sub-nav markup. This should be a minor issue as long as I can assign individual classes to the spans and change my css accordingly.

However, I can't get this to work.

TLDR: I was hoping that I could use pagerAnchorBuilder to create individual classes for each span. I can't. Help.

**The original markup (pre Cycle2) looks like the following:**

```html
<div id ="sub-nav" class="sub-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="available" class="available" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a id="reliable" class="reliable" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a id="use" class="use" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a id="reports" class="reports" href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a id="software" class="software" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>       
</div>

<div id="sliding-gallery" class="sliding-gallery home-content">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg">
            <section>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
            <p>Sed augue lacus pretium vitae molestie eget rhoncus quis elit. Fusce orci wisi vel ipsum in p</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
            </section>
        </li>
        <li>
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg">
            <section>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
            <p>Sed augue lacus pretium vitae molestie eget rhoncus quis elit. Fusce orci wisi vel ipsum in p</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
            </section>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <span id="#prev" class="prev">Previous</span>
    <span id="#next" class="next">Next</span>                   
</div>
```

**With Cycle2 it looks like this (note the addition of the span tags)**

```html
<div id ="sub-nav" class="sub-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="available" class="available" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a id="reliable" class="reliable" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a id="use" class="use" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a id="reports" class="reports" href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a id="software" class="software" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
<span class="cycle-pager-active">•</span><span>•</span><span>•</span><span>•</span><span>•</span></nav>         
</div>

<div id="sliding-gallery" class="sliding-gallery home-content">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg">
            <section>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
            <p>Sed augue lacus pretium vitae molestie eget rhoncus quis elit. Fusce orci wisi vel ipsum in p</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
            </section>
        </li>
        <li>
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg">
            <section>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
            <p>Sed augue lacus pretium vitae molestie eget rhoncus quis elit. Fusce orci wisi vel ipsum in p</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
            </section>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <span id="#prev" class="prev">Previous</span>
    <span id="#next" class="next">Next</span>                   
</div>
```

**Cycle2**

```js
$('#sliding-gallery ul').cycle({ 
    fx:     'carousel',
    carouselVisible: 1,     
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 10000,
    slides: '>li',      
    next:   '.next', 
    prev:   '.prev',
    pager:  '.sub-nav',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        return '.sub-nav span:eq(' + idx + ')';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope you are looking for something similar to this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k72Ay/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var slideshows = $('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-next cycle-prev', function(e, opts) {
    // advance the other slideshow
    slideshows.not(this).cycle('goto', opts.currSlide);
});

$('#cycle-2 .cycle-slide').click(function(){
    var index = $('#cycle-2').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex(this);
    slideshows.cycle('goto', index);
});

});
```

also you can find the above fiddle code on [cycle2 website](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caro-pager.php)

**can you provide your fiddle for this?**

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm not sure this will work. I've updated the mark-up and this should explain why. In short, The issue here is that the navigation and the gallery are actually individual elements. Cycle is acting on #sliding-gallery ul whereas the pager is a separate element outside #sliding-gallery. I could change this but it would requite a fair bit of refactoring.

Comment: @BertMurphy can you provide your fiddle for this?